# QGIS aggregate only specific values in a column

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, summarizing

I have a QGIS file (see img attached) and I want to calculate the same as `Area_HA` only with `CODE_06` between `100` and `500`.
I can't find the expression to add to the field calculator.

[image]

---

yes, I want to calculate the area in Ha for every objects that have CODE_06 bellow 500

Comment: The question is a bit misleading. You are not performing an aggregation, but a field calculation based on a condition.

Comment: When you say "aggregate" do you want to calculate the TOTAL area for every object that meets the condition (i.e. one area for all objects meeting the condition)?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you right, you use an expression that looks like:

`if ("Code_06" <= 500 AND "Code_06" >= 100, $area, '')`

Comment: Oh yeah exaclty!!! do you know how to do this operation in batch? meaning on several layers